# Statistical analyses of agent-based models outputs from several scenarios

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I developed an ABM to evaluate land use change and I tested 4 different scenarios, each scenarios contains some stochasticity and I therefore run each scenarios 40 times.

The 4 scenarios are made of 2 times 2 constrasting scenarios : 2 climate scenarios (1 and 2) and 2 economical scenarios (A and B). We therefore have the following combination:
1A - 1B - 2A - 2B

Among other analyses, I'd like to test if the two climatic scenarios lead to different output.

The first option I see is to consider each observation from each run as a repeated measure. I could therefore perform a two-way ANOVA with repeated measures.
The second option I see is to perform a three-way ANOVA where the "run" is a random factor and therefore we would have only one observation (n=1) for each combination of factors.

This is an open question to statistical advices.